# django-localeurl together with FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME not working

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

I'm currently working on a site where multiple locales will be served under different URLs using [django-localeurl](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-localeurl/). localeurl has always worked for me before when served directly at the top level but this time around I have to use [settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#force-script-name) because it needs to be served under a sub-path.

The problem is that when the user enters the site he is redirected to http://www.example.com/en/ and not http://www.example.com/site/en/ as he should be. Serving the site under http://www.example.com/site/ works perfectly when I disable localeurl.

Any suggestions as to how I could fix this would be greatly appreciated as I'm close to tearing my hair out any second now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open ticket](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-localeurl/issue/10/wrong-redirection-url) in locale-url for this issue. It also has a [proposed patch](https://bitbucket-assetroot.s3.amazonaws.com/carljm/django-localeurl/20100519/10/fix.patch) that fixes it.